# How to specify clean all build directories in yaml in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=schema#checkout we can have this:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
```

But as far as I understand the documentation it only cleans the source tree, not all the build directories.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Workspace clean** is probably what you want. You can define a workspace schema under the job and choose the resources to clean up.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace) for more information about workspace.

```yaml
  - job: myJob
    workspace:
      clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job
```

runs

Comment: I'm lost. It seems the correct answer, but when I open my YAML in AzureDevOps, I don't understand where do I add those lines. There is no `job` thing, only `trigger:` `pool:` `variables:` and then `steps:` with a "list" (whatever that is called in YAML) of `- task:`.

Comment: It goes at the same level as trigger, pool, variables

Comment: @Pac0 Put `jobs:` at the top level, give it one or more `- job:` elements, and put your `steps:` one level down inside one of those `- job:`.

Comment: `job` is also an optional command.  If you have only one, you may omit it and just include the next two lines ("workspace: \n clean: all")

Comment: How to clean it if we're using classic build pipeline?

Comment: ah, found it here for the classic version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679610/azure-devops-clean-build-directory

Comment: what are difference with those flags?