# How to clear last build files using azure ci cd pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have browser cache issue as from 1st build to 30 builds all the recent files are been storing in the path which are not been removed. How can I achieve when the build is successful previous file should be deleted from the location and new build files to be added.

Your inputs are Appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your azure-pipelines.yml?

Comment: if the files are inside a directory of the pipeline-agent you can set-up the clean-property of your pipeline like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690662/6593272

Comment: If the files are outside of the pipeline-agent you could add a powershell-task to your pipeline that cleans up the location